# What's an equation that could produce this kind of shape?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What kind of equation would produce a sort-of parabola, but the slope of the parabola gets less and less as x increases, but the slope always remains positive. The parabola would flatten out the higher it gets, essentially.

Comment: $x=y^2$ is an actual parabola... Perhaps it would help understanding what you mean if you could add a coarse sketch of the function you have in mind.

Comment: Would this “parabola” be a [hyperbola](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola) by any chance ?

Comment: The question is rather vague, but do you mean something like $y = \frac{x^2}{1 + x^2}$? Or $y = (\arctan x)^2$? Or $y = \tanh^2 x$? Or...?

Comment: @Travis Ah ha! I think you nailed it with the $y = (arctan  x)^2$ Is there a term for this kind of curve?

Comment: No, in fact, I've never seen a function like this in the wild, as it were; nonetheless, since you found it useful I'll promote my comment to an answer. If you can provide a little more context about why you're looking for such a function, someone may be able to offer a more natural suggestion.

Comment: @Travis There's no particular reason, I'm curious and experimenting with trying to make different curves.

Comment: So first the slope must increase to later decrease as it levels off, right? It must then have a point of inflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One curve roughly fitting this description is $y = (\arctan x)^2$.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is indeed what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found the answer helpful!

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x^2}}-\frac{1}{2}$$
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%201-exp%28-x%5E2%29) the sort of thing you want?

[image]

Comment: @Joe, thanks for the edit, I never know how to do that kind of thing ;-)

Comment: no problem. I'm on a Mac, and trimmed screenshot is pretty fast. Happy to help.